# best way to convert a simple decimal to hexadecimal and how much a 32 bit and 64 bit matters? decimal string? conversion?

Tags: c++, c, type-conversion, decimal

// eg how like 500 is converted into a F4 01 00 00 stuff and you can give references and link or tutorial video link also and please explain in easy words?

Comment: You're talking about converting decimal *strings* to hex strings right? And 500 is equivalent to 0x1F4, not 0xF4010000.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 it depends on the endian-ness of the 32 bit integer he is writing into.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I thought OP was talking about the hex equivalent of 500, not its byte placement. But yeah, I think in the case of little-endian byte placement it would be F4010000, so I misunderstood the sentence :P

Answer (score 1):

To convert 500 to hex, you do the same thing as if you wanted the base 10 digits: repeatedly divide by the base (decimal is 10, hex is 16) and store the remainder.

So, to convert 500 to hex:

- `500/16 = 31 remainder  4`  so we store 4 as the least significant digit
- `31/16 =  1 remainder 15`  so we store 15 (F) as the next least significant digit
- `1/16 =  0 remainder  1`  so we store 1 as the next significant digit(
- and we continue until we have however many digits we want.

So the hex number is `0x000001F4` but how is that stored in memory?

- some machines are big-endian and store the digits with the most significant byte in the lowest address so `0x000001F4` is stored in memory as:

  ```
  +----+----+----+----+
  | 00 | 00 | 01 | F4 |
  +----+----+----+----+
  ```
- some machines are little-endian and store the digits with the most significant byte in the highest address so `0x000001F4` is stored in memory as:

  ```
  +----+----+----+----+
  | F4 | 01 | 00 | 00 |
  +----+----+----+----+
  ```
- see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness for all the gory details on endian-ness